# The torsion subgroup of the group of units $R^{\times}$ is always equal to $\{\pm1\}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> In the ring of integers of the number field of degree $3$, the torsion subgroup of the group of units is always equal to $\{\pm1\}$

I found it [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=sZ5CAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=anthony%20knapp%20advanced%20algebra%20roots%20of%20unity&source=bl&ots=i3qROwwU9_&sig=gzHvjIjf4j50t_3lCDmv5eqIiEg&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ghY0VcDGIIu8ygPu7oHgBA&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=anthony%20knapp%20advanced%20algebra%20roots%20of%20unity&f=false) (Proposition $5.12$) only that the subgroup of $R^{\times}$ of the the elements of finite order consists all $l^{th}$ roots of unity in $\mathbb C$, where $l$ is a integer depending on $K$ that is bounded, when the degree $n=[K:\mathbb Q]$ is bounded, but in the proof I don't see any connection to $l$

or is it related to Dirichlet's Unit Theorem ?

Comment: Roots of unity (apart from those in $\mathbb Q$, $\pm 1$) are always of even degree over $\mathbb Q$, since the degrees of cyclotomic polynomials, computed by the Euler "totient" function, are always even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\zeta_l$ denotes a primitive $l^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, then the $l$ of interest is the largest number so that $\mathbb Q(\zeta_l)$ embeds into $\mathbb K$; your cited proof uses the fact that such an embedding requires $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_l):\mathbb Q] = \varphi(l) \le [\mathbb K:\mathbb Q]$ to prove the bound; it reduces to the claim that $\varphi(l) \to \infty$ as $l \to \infty$.

To solve your problem, you simply need to use the stronger fact that, if $\mathbb Q(\zeta_l)$ embeds into $\mathbb K$, then $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_l):\mathbb Q]$ divides $[\mathbb K:\mathbb Q]$.

Comment: Your last sentence is true because the degree of a tower of field extensions is multiplicative. And $\phi$ is never $3$, so $l=2$, am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$